# Why does this "proof" using Gaussian Elimination on an infinite sequence of vectors not work?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the following problem from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT8FrJlhqsY) (very awesome!) video.

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ has $0 < |\alpha| < 1$, and defining the vectors $f_k = (1, \alpha^k, \alpha^{2k}, \alpha^{3k}, \dots) \in \mathcal{l}^2$ (so that each vector is a geometric sequence that is square summable), prove that the span of all $f_k$'s ($k = 1$ to $\infty$) is equal to $\mathcal{l}^2$ itself.

Here's an idea I had, but I feel like something here isn't correct or sufficient to establish a correct proof. The idea is to do Gaussian Elimination on the $f_k$'s in sequence to get vectors $g_k$, and then given a vector $v \in \mathcal{l}^2$, we can piece together $v$ one component at a time using the next $g_i$. This is just like what we do in normal linear algebra.

For example,
$g_1 = f_1 = (1, \alpha^1, \alpha^2, \dots)$.

$g_2 = f_2 - g_1 = (1, \alpha^1, \alpha^2, \dots) - (1, \alpha^2, \alpha^4, \dots) = (0, \alpha-\alpha^2, \alpha^2 - \alpha^4, \dots).$

And we can keep going, using the previous $g_k$ to eliminate another coordinate. Thus $g_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_{ik} f_i$ for some $\beta_{ik}$. Finally, we can easily express $v$ in terms of the $g_k$, going one coordinate at a time. The end result is that we have expressed $v$ as a linear combination of the $g_k$, and thus the $f_k$.

This proof doesn't feel sufficient. Is there anything wrong with it or that's missing?

Comment: There is a problem, because you will get a representation of $ v$ of the form $\sum a_kf_k$, but the equality holds only termwise. The series is not convergent with respect to $\ell^2$ norm. Observe  that the set $f_{2k}$ is  also linearly dense in $\ell^2$, as we can replace $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc do you mind expanding this into a full answer?